# Three.js imported object different starting positions

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.js and I have a problem. I've imported external 3D object (.obj extension) and I add it to my scene. I want to set newly imported object at (0, 0, 0) position, so I use:

```
obj.position.set(0, 0, 0);
```

I expect that object would be placed at 0 point of each axis from axis helper. However it doesn't happen. Object is placed at its own position:

[image]

Why is that happening and how can I set object position to (0, 0, 0) and make it appear right at 0 point of each axis?

Comment: It will depend on what the objects position is when it is exported from the 3d app.

Comment: It also depends of the position of the object you place it in if you put it in a group i.e

Comment: Objects are added directly to scene. I thought that it might depend on conditions made by 3d app which was used to create model, but in that case - how can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to center your imported object(s) at the origin like so:

```js
const aabb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( obj );
const center = aabb.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3() );

obj.position.x += ( obj.position.x - center.x );
obj.position.y += ( obj.position.y - center.y );
obj.position.z += ( obj.position.z - center.z );
```

The idea is to compute the axis-aligned bounding box of the object and use its center property for the actual centering.

Comment: Technically it wasn't solution I was looking for - but it still does trick and works. Thanks!